# Given an a variable or equation how do I say that I raise (aribitrary variable name) by both sides of an equation?

Tags: terminology

Exponentiation is a mathematical operation, written as $b^n$, involving two numbers, the base b and the exponent or power n, and pronounced as "b raised to the power of n".

So when I have an equation like $x=3$ and transform it to $x^c=3^c$ I would also call it "Exponentation"  or raising both sides of the equation to the power of c.

But what if in contrast I transform $x=3$ to $c^x=c^3$ would that still be called "Exponentation" and if so how would I describe it in words?
Raising $c$ by both sides of an equation?

Comment: First case mentioned I would call raising both sides to the power of $c$.  The second mentioned case is referred to as exponentiating both sides (with base $c$).

Comment: This seems to be more of an English question than a math question. Since you know the English phrase "$b$ raised to the power of $n$", all you need to know is that preserving the preposition "to" is important to English. So it would be "raising $c$ *to* both sides of an equation", not "raising $c$ by both sides".